# Deserializing external web service, XML into class object in .NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, xml-deserialization

I have have had some trouble with generating objects from a external web service.

I call the web service with a httpRequest like http://./ucs-ws?requserstatus&user=testuser

WebserviceClient.cs

```
    public string UserStatus(string userName)
    {
        string req = "req=userStatus";
        string user = "user=" + userName;
        string result;
        using (WebClient proxy = new WebClient())
        {
            proxy.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("br:br"));
            proxy.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/xml");

            try
            {
                var response = proxy.DownloadString(webServiceBasePath + req + "&" + user);


                result = response;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Web Service not available. Please contact the Administrator";
            }



        }
        return result;
    }
```

The response I get from the external web service is

```
<Result>
        <UserStatus 
                 Status="34" 
                 StatusFrom="140729143619" 
                 ClientType="4" 
                 LogOnServer="NcoreConnect" 
                 SIPServer="10.16.3.10" 
                 Device="tel:201" 
                 DeviceStatus="0" 
                 DeviceStatusFrom="140729134828" 
                 ServerTime="140731090408" 
                 IsLoggedOn="True" 
                 IsAgent="True" 
                 CallCount="0" 
                 AnsweredCount="0" 
                 Interactions="" 
                 Message="" 
                 SessionID="a123a38d-d00d-47c0-af03-2b63f40fb8a6" 
                 DiversionStatus="0" 
                 DiversionDestination="" 
                 OldMessageCount="0" 
                 NewMessageCount="0">testuser
         </UserStatus>
</Result>
```

What I need is to make an userStatus object, that I can add to a list. with the variables from userStatus.

Those anyone know if theres a smart way to do it so you have a class like this:

UserStatus.cs

```
public class UserStatus
{
     [XmlElement("UserStatus")]
     public string UserName; // testuser

     public string Status;

     public string StatusFrom;

     public string ClientType;

     public string LogOnServer;

     ...
}
```

It would be nice if someone could help me or lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the XML provided, the following should work

```
[XmlRoot("Result")]
public class UserStatusResult 
{
    [XmlElement]
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class UserStatus
{
    [XmlText]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string StatusFrom { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.